# HTML CSS layout pushing elements down the page

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
<div>
```

and I'm trying to create this layout

[image]

1, 3 and 3 are set to display block and width of 33%.
4 is set to inline-block and width of 60%

The layout appears as I want it to but as I add content to 4, it pushes 1, 2 and 3 down the page so it's not top aligned.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Instead of describing your CSS, please add your actual code to the question.

Comment: "1, 3, and 3" you mean 1 3 and 4? 1 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, Flexbox is our lord and saviour. Here's your layout made with Flex.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  border: #00f solid 2px;
}

.container .side {
  border: #ff0 dashed 3px;
  flex-basis: 33%;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* Prevents shrinking if .four grows */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between; /* Ensures perfect spacing of the elements on the left */
}

.container .side div {
  background: #008000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}

.container .four {
  border: #f00 solid 3px;
  flex-grow: 1; /* Take remaining space */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="side">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="four"></div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `.four`

reason: inline-blocks are by default (vertically) aligned along their baseline, which is the lowest line of text, if there *is* any text - this changes that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap 1,2 and 3 in another div, and then rather than `inline-block` make it simply

```
display: block;
float: left;
```